A question about syntactic function of the clause
Given:

He told me the secret how he had done well in the exam.

In this sentence, the ditransitive verb tell here has the following core arguments, with each of these noun phrases performing a different syntactic function:

Subject: he
Direct object: the secret
Indirect object: me

That much of the syntax is clear, but what of the remaining clause how he had done well in the exam? What is the syntactic function of that entire clause with respect to the other constituents in this sentence?

It's an adjectival clause modifying "the secret" but I'm not sure how it's a relative clause (I don't think how is a relative pronoun). How has some funny usage rules in English, and while this is ok in colloquial speech I fear a pedant would condemn it.

Where is the source sentence from? It does not seem grammatical, and Google ngrams suggests that collocation occurs in print only with some punctuation, usually a colon, between them. But “secret of how” is unremarkable.

It's an "interrogative content clause" but "the secret" is unnecessary and could be left out.

@user405662 And what is its syntactic Function? Is it an complement or modifier?

@Salimuddin The clause in bold is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement, but preferably of the preposition "of", as in "He told me the secret of how he had done well in the exam."

@BillJ Is it a complement of the verb or the phrase 'the secret'?

@BillJ but many say it is an adjective clause that modifies the D.O..

In your example, complement of the verb, but of preposition "of" in my suggested alternant.

@Salimuddin That would be an impossible analysis. 'Adjective clauses' are relative clauses, which is clearly not the case here.

@BillJ Are you suggesting according to cgel?

The meaning is: "He told me the secret of the answer to the question 'How well had he done in the exam?'"

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In colloquial speech in the Philadelphia area, you'll hear people say things like "Joe's an old-timer and can show you the trick how to do it." referring to some clever approach in a DIY home-repair or similar. That's similar to your "secret how".

Following on from what Tim says, this usage appears to be dialectal rather than standard English. In speech of course, as tchrist implies, 'He told me the secret: how he had done well in the exam.' works, and the colon or dash is disguised as a pause, but in written form punctuation is needed (or a preposition) to give an unarguably grammatical string.

I recommend not trying to make too much of this exotic, seldom heard construction. You can analyse it like you do a reason+why or place+where or time+when clauses, but it is not standard English today as written. At least, that was the opinion of one of our resident linguistics professors here. It turns out that in a comment from almost a decade ago now, the late Professor Lawler once wrote, with bold emphasis added by me:

This is exacerbated in relative pronouns; how is a wh-word for manner or means, but even when it modifies manner, means, or way, it can't occur as a relative pronoun: *the way how it's done, *the means how to do it, *the manner how to curtsey, etc. It's not a matter of "redundancy", exactly -- redundancy is a feature of all language, and not necessarily a bug. In this case, the grammar has gotten all gnarly after so long without inflections, and relative clauses are very complex syntactically.

Therefore in standard English, the sentence presented by the asker is ungrammatical as written. Just because it may nonetheless still be found from time to time in regional dialects, at least historically, so can any number of constructions used only by a few native speakers from a restricted time and place, ones most native speakers would now hold to be ungrammatical for them.

It may be ungrammatical here because the how clause should be complement of the prep "of".  But if "of" is added, I'd say that the how clause is a subordinate interrogative, meaning "He told me the secret of the answer to the question 'How well had he done in the exam?'"

This has to do with nominal clauses (of the particular type called "wh- interrogative clauses*, or what in the terminology of CGEL (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language) one calls "content clauses"; this latter term, however, which gives to the concept a semantic flavour, does not seem as satisfactory as "nominal clause", which evoques a specific content word, that is the noun (after all, verbs and adjectives are also content words and these clauses are not apparented syntactically either to verbs or adjectives). That is why I will adhere (at least for the time being) to a terminology which I consider superior because it is more specific, that is, to the term  "nominal clause", to be found as that retained in A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language (CoGEL).

(CoGEL § 7.15) Adjunct adverb and conjunction  […]
Where, when, why, and how are all used to introduce nominal clauses
[…]:

That is how  they treated her. [4]



(CoGEL § 15.2) Functional classes of subordinate clauses
On the basis of their potential functions, we distinguish several major
categories of subordinate clauses: NOMINAL, ADVERBIAL, RELATIVE, and
COMPARATIVE. The functional classification resembles to some extent that of
subclausal units such as noun phrases and adverbs.
NOMINAL CLAUSES have functions that approximate to those of noun
phrases: subject, object, complement, appositive, and prepositional complement. Every nominal clause may function in some or all of these functions.
Unlike noun phrases, however, nominal clauses may also function as
adjective complementation without a preposition […]:

I'm not sure that Ican remember the exact details.

The privilege of occurrence of nominal clauses is more limited than that of
noun phrases because semantically the clauses are normally abstract; ie they
refer to such abstractions as events, facts, dates, and ideas rather than to
perceptible objects.


(CoGEL § 15.5) Wh-interrogative clauses
Subordinate wh-interrogative clauses occur in the whole range of functions
available to the nominal that-clause […] and in addition may function as
prepositional complement:

subject: How the book will sell depends on the reviewers.
direct object: I can't imagine what they want with your address.
subject complement: The problem is who will water my plants when I am
away.
appositive: Your original question, why he did not report it to the police earlier, has not yet been answered.
adjectival complementation: I'm not sure which she prefers.
prepositional complement: They did not consult us on whose names should
be put forward.


In the case of the OP's sentence it can be seen that the syntactic function is that of prepositional complement.  The first observation is "But there is no peposition."; the answer to that is that there is a preposition but is has been ellipted according to a certain indeterminate practice   (somewhat similar to the established practice of ellipting the subordinator "that") of suppressing the preposition, which is "of". This can be seen from the review of numerous sentences taken from the explanations in CoGEL, in which a perhaps more formal attitude results in a consistent use of "of" (all examples below from CoGEL, user LPH's bold type).

[…] may well contain only inflections
together with a detailed explanation of how the phonological system emerged. (Ellipting does not seem possible.)

A FORMAL classification takes account of how a unit is composed of smaller units or components. (Ellipting does not seem possible.)

Such arguments, however, have more to do with the labelling of categories
than with the question of how we can best explain the grammatical behaviour of items on the basis of their various degrees of similarity and contrast.(Ellipting does not seem possible.)

[…]  seems to be largely a matter of how far the name
is an institutionalized name among English-speaking (and in this case
particularly British) people. (Ellipting does not seem possible.)


A study of the following Google Book data, that is a study of the examples where an ellipted construction is used and where it is not, or some such set of data, might reveal what makes the ellipting possible, but that is the subject of another ELU question.

the secret how (numerous false positives will be found, very rare ellipting of the preposition)
(Dana and the Secret of the Magic Crystal
Thomas L. Hunter · 2017)  "If you find out how they managed to capture me, and if you solve the secret how they neutralized my powers, then I'm in."
the secret of how

Massive chunks copied from some textbook are not very helpful, particularly from the Comprehensive which is out of date, CGEL being more up-to-date and far superior.

@BillJ I don't think The Comprehensive is out of date; it has its defects, agreed. In this particular case of nomenclatture (nominal clause, content clauses) I do prefer the Comprehensive, and I say why (not to be ignored - refute the argument if you can).

Not sure whether to ding you for the claim "new tendency" of suppressing the preposition.  https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Complete_Works_of_Stephen_Charnock_B/BAtKAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22method+how+it%22&pg=PA508&printsec=frontcover

"Though these promises and prophecies of the expiation and cleansing of sin were something obscure to them and though they did not exactly know the method how it would be accomplished yet that sin should be pardoned was fully revealed and something of the method of it might be known unto them " (1865).

@TimR Itgives the impression of a new trend to me but your example shows that it's probably subjective. I'll change that.

"And as a step stone to any recovery the third section directs the method how it shall be ascertained where the legal settlement of a pauper is to wit by the examination and adjudication of two jus tices of the peace giving power to make an or der of removal and to carry their doings into effect if necessary by issuing their warrant of removal to an officer authorized to execute it." (1888)

"THE planter being now instructed in the manner of planting and heading down of wall trees it is proper I should give directions with regard to the method how they are to be pruned and reared against the wall, for without pruning you never will be able to fill your wall properly with bearing branches nor to keep it full." The Fruit Gardener (1768).

I suspect that "of" is the newfangled development, possibly pedagogical in origin. Might be worth exploring.

In "He told me the secret of [how he had done well in the exam]", the  bracketed clause is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of the preposition "of". Some would say that it's an oblique complement. The meaning is "He told me the secret of the answer to the question 'How well had he done in the exam?'" We don't use the term 'nominal clause' nowadays for the reasons given in CGEL pp 1014-17.

@BillJ Given how any number of time- and place-nouns work for time+when and place+where clauses yet pretty much the only reason-noun that works with reason+why clauses is reason itself, the question seems to be one of determining exactly which (if any) manner-nouns are allowable in manner+how clauses — and whether secret is really one of those.

CoGEL's classification (nominal, adjectival and adverbial) is based on functional analogies between the subordinate clauses and the three word categories. CGEL rejects this analysis, claiming that the classification of finite subordinate clauses should be based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech. CGEL's arguments are compelling and it is for this reason that it trumps CoGEL, not just here but most everywhere else.

@LPH. No, it's not true. Stick to the syntax. It's tempting to see it as a relative clause, with "how" meaning "the way that". But "how" does not belong to the class of relative words, though it occurs freely in subordinate interrogatives., which is what the how clause is here. And it's not a nominal clause, as I've already explained.

@BillJ Those are just personal convictions that I have not properly assessed, not sufficiently analysed so as to come to a solid conclusion (what  would be a solid conclusion from my point of view, which can possibly be wrong). Notice that I do not use that contention in my answer.
